# Connecting to QuickBooks Online IPP

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am making a QuickBooks Online app. How do my customers obtain this information:

- Access Key
- Access Key Secret
- Consumer Key
- Consumer Key Secret

My docs are here:

http://www.jmawebtechnologies.com/support-blog/january-2013/nopcommerce-quickbooks-online-set-up-and-installat

In my Intuit developer portal, I have these 4 pieces of information. I have an app profile:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/Create_An_App_Profile

Will each customer have a different access key, access key secret, consumer key and consumer key secret? Based on my experience, it appears only realmId (Company ID) changes and the other info stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an app profile as per the instructions provided on this page -https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/Create_An_App_Profile
you would be provided with a consumer key and secret. You would need to use this key for the oauth handshake to obtain the access token and secret.

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App

Every user will be provided a new access token and secret, but the consumer key/secret will be the same for all users of your app.

Comment: Joseph, users do not need that information only your application does. Users will login to their Intuit accounts, and grant your application permission to their data, then you use the key/secret pairs to access their data via the APIs.

Comment: I see what he is saying. I use the oauthgrant and oauthhandler here https://code.intuit.com/integration/viewvc/viewvc.cgi/IntuitAnywhere-.NET/HelloIntuitAnywhere/HelloIntuitAnywhere/?root=intuitanywhere&system=exsy1003 to generate this info.